# spring cloud:How to implement a database transaction in api gateway?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

How to implement a database transaction in api gateway?

```
 @Transactional
 @RequestMapping(value = UserConstants.USERS_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public void save(@RequestBody User user) {
    //save two model
    UserEntity ue = userService.save(user.reverseEntity());
    VideoEntity ve = videoService.save(user.getVideo().reverseEntity());
   //service load by eureka + feign
  }
```

I want save two model with different service in one transaction.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about the concrete goal you try to achieve?

Comment: I want save one user contains videos,save user and video two model with two service in one transaction

Comment: So what did you tried so far, why didn't it work? I think it could be helpful if you provide some sample code in your question, pointing to the concrete part, your question belongs to.
I looked in your sample-project but I can just find a User-Model and a Controller. I think you need to be a **lot** more specific to get helpful answers ;-)

Comment: i edit question,hope you understand it.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Doesn't the @Transactional Annotation provide the behaviour you expect?

Comment: @Transactional not work in controller

Comment: Maybe you could create a "Wrapper-Service" which encapsulates the userService and videoService methods? This can be called from Controller then. 
  
`@Service 
public class WrapperService{   
  @Transactional public void save(User user){  
    UserEntity ue = userService.save(user.reverseEntity());   
    VideoEntity ve = videoService.save(user.getVideo().reverseEntity());      
    //...   
  }  
}  
`